# Display monthname in other language

Tags: sql-server

In my view, I want to display the MonthName in German. How can I change the monthname from English to German.  `DATENAME(month, getdate()) AS 'MonthName'`

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you can use [`FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM', 'de-de')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

try:

see languages,

by `SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages`

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS 'MonthName'

SET LANGUAGE German
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS 'MonthName'

SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS 'MonthName'
```

Comment: Insert the command in the view, I become this message, SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.". Also when i execute only the command in the view "SET LANGUAGE german. But if i create a new query in SMS it works.

Comment: The error is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Spanish' at line 1`. WampServer 3.1.9 64bit doesn't seem to recognize `Spanish`.

Comment: it's for SqlServer,Not MySQL!!

Comment: Actually this is not the best way to achive this because this command changes all the context language, this can be harmful. Suggest to use solution below.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to get month names in other languages using `FORMAT` function:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2019-10-18';

SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'MMMM', 'en-US') AS YourMonthName -- OUTPUT: October
SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'MMMM', 'es-es') AS YourMonthName -- OUTPUT: octubre
SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'MMMM', 'zh-cn') AS YourMonthName -- OUTPUT: 十月
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with MariaDB version 10.3.2 or superior, try this one:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2020-01-01', '%M', 'es_ES') as Month;
```

```
+--------------------+
| Month              |
+--------------------+
| Enero              |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
SET lc_time_names = ' (your language)';
```

Full list here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html